# Karate- get value of a field from response in another feature file

Tags: variables, karate

I have a scenario where i need to get a specific field from a response of another feature file and re-use it.

Scenario:-
Feature file A deals with POST where i get a response and save the field userId in a variable myuser.
Sample response:-
{
user:"123"
tier:"diamond"
}

i save the value as *def myuser =response.user

I want to call feature file A from another feature file B.
I do not want to pass any parameter to feature file A.
My code looks like

- def ReponseA = read('classpath:FeaturefileA.feature')
- def currentuser =ResponseA.user

This might be incorrect.My basic need is to get the myuser value from Feature file A to a variable in Feature file B and use in sceanrios for feature file B.Kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a.feature)
Feature file A:
POST Method which gives you response as follows:

```
{ user:"123" tier:"diamond" }
```

(b.feature)
Feature file B:

```
 * def fileA = call read('../FOLDER NAME/a.feature')
 * def fileAResponse = fileA.response
 * print fileAResponse
```

the above code in b.feature will print the response of a.feature

Hope this is what you want?

Comment: Thanks Ankit.I could extract the response and the exact field as required.

Comment: @Ankit How can I call a variable from another feature file?